# Scrapy setting boolean with ItemLoader

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to set a boolean item in my Items with

`l.add_value('is_english', True)`

But I get an error because the default output processor 'strip' cannot handle a boolean. Other l.add_value statements all work fine.

Default setting in pipeline is False. Most spiders will simply use False, but some will need to toggle this Item to True.

EDIT: Full spider code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from kbla_scrapes1.items import ThisScrapesItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, Compose, MapCompose, Join
from w3lib.html import replace_escape_chars, remove_tags
from scrapy.loader.processors import Identity

class MyLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = ThisScrapesItem
    rel_english = Identity()

class BokecSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'thisspider'
    allowed_domains = ['this.org']
    start_urls = ['www.this.org']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/span/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        l = MyLoader(response=response)
        l.default_output_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), replace_escape_chars)

        l.add_value('rel_org', 'This Org')
        l.add_css('rel_title', '.subject::text')
        l.add_css('rel_summary', '.dbData')
        l.add_css('rel_scraped_date', '.date::text')
        l.add_value('rel_url', response.url)
        l.add_value('rel_english', True)
        yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: Are you using an `ItemLoader`? If yes, could you add the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Identity()` in your ItemLoader:

If you are using an `input_processor`, use `rel_english_in = Identity()`

```
class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MyItem
    default_input_processor = ....
    rel_english_in = Identity()
```

If you are using an `output_processor`, use `rel_english_out = Identity()`:

```
class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MyItem
    default_output_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), replace_escape_chars)
    rel_english_out = Identity()
```

---

Based on the code you've added, I've updated it and it works as expected. I had to add some extra code to make it work since you didn't add all the pieces required to run:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Identity
from w3lib.html import replace_escape_chars


class MyItem(Item):
    rel_english = Field()
    rel_url = Field()
    rel_org = Field()
    rel_title = Field()
    rel_summary = Field()
    rel_scraped_date = Field()


class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MyItem
    default_output_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), replace_escape_chars)
    rel_english_out = Identity()


class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "reddit"
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': "reddit_comments.csv", 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}

    def start_requests(self):

        random_start_urls = [
            "https://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/lb6a3/im_meeting_with_some_people_helping_to_bring_evs/",
            "http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1b4a3b/prospective_buyer_question_what_is_a_home/",
            "http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1f5dmm/any_rav4_ev_drivers_on_reddit/",
        ]

        for url in random_start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        l = MyItemLoader(selector=response)
        l.add_value('rel_org', 'This Org')
        l.add_css('rel_title', '.subject::text')
        l.add_css('rel_summary', '.dbData')
        l.add_css('rel_scraped_date', '.date::text')
        l.add_value('rel_url', response.url)
        l.add_value('rel_english', True)
        yield l.load_item()
```

More info can be found in here in the docs:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.Identity

Comment: Thanks. I added the parsing code above. I'm not using a custom ItemLoader, just the default.

Comment: No problem. If your issue has been solved, please accept my code as the answer.

Comment: I can't say if it has or not since I still can't make it work.